# How to pass array value to the function of javascript? PHP Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have an array in the javascript named as country_id[] and selected_country[]. When the user select the country in country array, it will save inside the country_id[] array and when the user select the country inside the selected country, it will save inside the selected_country[] . Then, I want to pass the value of country_id[] and selected_country[] to the function at script function. This is to move the data from right to left and left to right. The picture is attached here. [image]

But it says that, error below.

ERROR :

```
179:575 Uncaught ReferenceError: country_id is not defined
```

Form :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('admin-insurance-region-duplicateRegion')}}" onsubmit="return false;">
            @csrf
        <input name="id" value="{{$region->id}}" type="hidden" class="form-control" required>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Choose Country</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="country_id[]" multiple  size="10" style="height: 100%;">
                        @foreach ($countries as $item)
                        <option  value="{{$item->id}}" selected>{{$item->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Selected Country</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="selected_country[]" multiple  size="10" style="height: 100%;">
                        @foreach ($country_region as $item)
                            <option  value="{{$item->id}}" selected>{{$item->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onclick="moveRight()">Move option to the right</button>
            <button onclick="moveLeft()">Move option to the Left</button>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
<script>


        function moveRight() {

            var selItem = document.forms[0].country_id.selectedIndex;
            if (selItem == -1) {
                window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
            } else {
                document.forms[0].selected_country.add(document.forms[0].country_id[selItem], null);
            }
        }

        function moveLeft() {
            var selItem = document.forms[0].selected_country.selectedIndex;
            if (selItem == -1) {
                window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
            } else {
                document.forms[0].country_id.add(document.forms[0].selected_country[selItem], null);
            }
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Id attribute within 'country' and 'selected country' select box.

like.

```
<select class="form-control" id="country_id" name="country_id[]" multiple  size="10">
  -----
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="selected_country" name="selected_country[]" multiple  size="10">
 -----                
</select>
```

DEMO.

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{route('admin-insurance-region-duplicateRegion')}}" onsubmit="return false;">
 <label>Choose Country</label>
 <select class="form-control" id="country_id" name="country_id[]" multiple  size="10">
  <option  value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option  value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option  value="3" selected>3</option>
 </select>
 <label>Selected Country</label>
 <select class="form-control" id="selected_country" name="selected_country[]" multiple  size="10">
  <option  value="s1" selected>s1</option>
  <option  value="s2" selected>s2</option>
  <option  value="s3" selected>s3</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 <button onclick="moveRight()">Move option to the right</button>
 <button onclick="moveLeft()">Move option to the Left</button>
</div>

<script>
function moveRight() {

var selItem = document.forms[0].country_id.selectedIndex;
 if (selItem == -1) {
 window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
 } else {
 document.forms[0].selected_country.add(document.forms[0].country_id[selItem], null);
 }
}

function moveLeft() {
 var selItem = document.forms[0].selected_country.selectedIndex;
 if (selItem == -1) {
 window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
 } else {
 document.forms[0].country_id.add(document.forms[0].selected_country[selItem], null);
 }
}

</script>
```